# Save result of find and md5sum commands into array for further processing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to save the result of find+md5sum commands for a further processing inside a for loop. How to save it into array variable properly? Here is a part of my script with some test data:

```sh
IFS=\n
FILES_1=($(find ${DIR_1} -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -k 2))

i=0
for line in ${FILES_1[*]} ; do
  echo ${line}
  i=$(($i+1))
done
echo ${i} #just for check
```

**Result**:

```
d0c096a5b5d91ab188723713fd5e6357  test/dir1/dir/qwerty.py
e90d6e2e9e0e4554d902fe84b6e08604  test/dir1/dir/source.py
e98cf83497d25feea1e37274183744c3  test/dir1/file.txt
e5bd0a793460559be2e689d39ad9f037  test/dir1/file2.txt
222bec76ce8f3afc0b44ae409d2b03bf  test/dir1/script1.py
bdd50254b0036bc6b7c136f335f1460e  test/dir1/script2.py
eead78462722fce1e7e27a2ec69b78bd  test/dir1/script3.py
7f609c0dd1490a5e8e4f69ddcdec6500  test/dir1/script4.py
3d4f2eb5d55096a02214e21701a472fa  test/dir1/script5.py
```

So, after execution i = 1, not 9. And I can't access a certain element by index (i). I mean I'm expecting to see one (first) string if I write "echo ${FILES_1[0]}" but I see them all and see nothing if "echo ${FILES_1[1]}".
Seems like it's just one string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=\n
```

You set your input field separator to \ slash (literal slash) or `n` (literal letter `n`). There are no slashes or `n` in your input, so all gets assigned to the first element of the array.

You want:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

The `$'...'` construct expands escape sequences inside it to another characters. The `\n` escape sequence gets expanded inside `$''` to a newline (0x0a in hex).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the md5sum as value of an associative array with file path as key

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A arr
while IFS=' ' read -r -d '' v k; do
  arr[$k]="$v"
done < <(find . -type f -exec md5sum --zero {} +)
```

Then

```sh
echo "${arr["test/dir1/script1.py"]}"
```

Would print:

```
222bec76ce8f3afc0b44ae409d2b03bf
```

Comment: oh, sounds good but "syntax error near unexpected token `<'" and "`done < <(find ${DIR_2} -type f -exec md5sum --zero {} +)'"

Comment: and "declare -A" does not work in my case: "declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]"

Comment: sorry, it's fine, bash version was too old

Comment: md5sum: stat '--zero': No such file or directory

Comment: The `--zero` option is only available with GNU CoreUtils. Given the issues you encounter with my code witch requires Bash 4+ and GNU CoreUtils I guess you are using a MacOS's provided Bash 3.2 and its BSD tools witch works quite differently.

Comment: `echo "${arr['test/dir1/script1.py']}"` this gives a syntax error, you shouldn't single-quote array subscripts.

Answer (score -2):

Try `((i=i+1))` instead of `i=$(($i+1))` for the counter variable.

To populate an array, do this:

```
x=()
*for loop*
x += (next element)
*end of for loop*
```

Comment: 1. `((i=i+1))` and `i=$(($i+1))` do the same thing (they only differ for exit status when `i=-1`). 2. You don't need `$` inside `$((`, just `i=$((i+1))`